# How to get the value of `dynamic_date_format` and other mapping Elasticsearch settings

Tags: elasticsearch

New to Elasticsearch, and we are wondering how to check the current value of `dynamic_date_formats`.

The official online document, [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html#_customizing_detected_date_formats), provides the below example of setting customized value, but we did not find how to get its value. Either an API call or a sample URL command will help.

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "dynamic_date_formats": ["MM/dd/yyyy"]
  }
}
```

Also, we are looking into the other arguments of the mapping settings, e.g., the [Mapping limit settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-settings-limit.html#mapping-settings-limit), including `index.mapping.total_fields.limit` and others. So, we wonder how to check the values of these arguments as well.

We highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the `index.mapping.total_fields.limit` or any other settings from an index using the command below:

```
GET index/_settings?include_defaults=true&filter_path=**.total_fields
```

Regarding `dynamic_date_formats`, either you have specified it when creating your index and you can retrieve the value using the command below:

```
GET test/_mapping?filter_path=**.dynamic_date_formats
```

Or you haven't specified it and the [default value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-field-mapping.html#date-detection) is the following that you can hardcode into your logic

```
[ "strict_date_optional_time","yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z||yyyy/MM/dd Z"]
```

Comment: We have resolved the issue: 1) for `total_fields` in the settings, use `GET /my-index-000001/_settings?include_defaults=true&filter_path=**.total_fields`, and 2) for `dynamic_date_formats` in the mappings, use `GET /my-index-000001/_mapping?include_defaults=true&filter_path=**.dynamic_date_formats`.